# Sidekiq what is the best way we can fetch limited number of data by an api call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I am new on sidekiq. my site is deploy in heroku

and in my code I have declare `config/sidekiq.yml`

```
# Place this file at config/sidekiq.yml and Sidekiq will
# pick it up automatically.
---
:verbose: false
:concurrency: 20

# Set timeout to 8 on Heroku, longer if you manage your own systems.
:timeout: 30

# Sidekiq will run this file through ERB when reading it so you can
# even put in dynamic logic, like a host-specific queue.
# http://www.mikeperham.com/2013/11/13/advanced-sidekiq-host-specific-queues/


# you can override concurrency based on environment
production:
  :concurrency: 25
staging:
  :concurrency: 15
```

In my workeer I have fetch the data from api

My Procfile is `worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml`

My worker is look like

```
class SfApifetch
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options retry: false
  def perform(name, count)
    # do something
    Net::Http...rest of the code
  end
end
```

Can anyone suggest how can I fetch the data in batch limit wise like I want to fetch 1000 record first page then fetch 1000 record in this way so that it did not hamper the performance but improve the speed.

I am new on sidekiq and BG any suggestion will be a great help for me

I have follow http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq?view=asciicast

Comment: Can you please post your Worker.

Comment: ok I amposting the worker

Comment: @spickermann thanks you for showing interest on my post .. please suggest how can I optimize it to fetch the data by faster way with 1000 , 1000, 1000 in this way page wise

Comment: Does the external resource support pagination or batches?

Comment: no the external api did not support pagination and batches as well

Comment: Seems impossible to load data in batches, when the external API does not support batches, pagination, limits or offsets. Isn't it?

Comment: I do not know it make my page load high and give me low performance heroku make ot slow I increase concurrency and also reliable fetch option too but no hope ....is there any way in configuration to fetch all of them faster way instead my configuration?...Please help me @spickermann

Answer (score 1):

If the external API provides some `id` or other unique field you could save it to the some variable and pass it to the next worker call, e.g.

```
class AwesomeWorker
  LIMIT = 1000

  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(name, count, last_id = nil)
    # fetching data from last_id, limited by LIMIT
    # fetching from the beginning if last_id is nil

    # running worker with id of the last record
    AwesomeWorker.perform_async(name, count, data.last_id)
  end
end
```